# Displaying code only for certain countries

Tags: php

So I have an affiliate program that's lately been getting a lot of bad leads from countries we don't service, which we tell affiliates will be voided. Anyways, this is going to cause our reversal rate to be through the roof. So I want to do something about it.

So I want to use geoip, which gets me the stuff as a 2 letter country code.

```
<?php
    $output = shell_exec('geoip-lookup '.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
?>
```

So how do I put that together?

Would this be correct?

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('geoip-lookup '.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
if($_SESSION['check']!=1) && ($output=='US' || $output=='AU' || $output=='GB' || $output=='CA')
{
    $submission = $_POST['submission_id'];
    $_SESSION['check']=1;
    echo 'insert pixel';
}
?>
```

Comment: Why bother with an external executable when there's [native PHP code](http://www.maxmind.com/app/php) for this?

Comment: @Andrew, you shouldn't be "fixing" your question to include the corrections by those answering below or else they will no longer apply and any future person reading this will be confused. It's best to leave the errors in there.

Comment: @Jon, I wouldn't call what you mentioned *native*. :) It's an extension or module. *Native* PHP are things like `strpos()` or the SPL library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to verify `$output` is what you expect (i.e. a string - `var_dump($output)`).

However, provided it is, you'll need to quote your country codes to do a string comparison. Also, as noted by **heximal**, be sure to use `==` for comparison. Otherwise, it's an assignment.

```
if ($_SESSION['check'] != 1 && ($output == 'US' || $output == 'AU' ...)) {
```

Otherwise, the rest of you code *appears* correct (without knowing your exact logic).

Comment: No problem. Welcome to StackOverflow. A reminder to up vote the answers you found helpful and ultimately mark one that *best* answered *your* question.

Comment: it's giving me a small error...I'm guessing I need another bracket? if(($_SESSION['check']!=1) && ($output=='US' || $output=='AU' || $output=='GB' || $output=='CA'))

Comment: The brackets you posted are right. I've also updated my answer as they were misleading. Try again. If not you can comment back or post a new question with the error message.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with "geoip-lookup" but I have "geoiplookup" working in my Ubuntu shell. Hopefully I can assume they are the same?

Putting $_SERVER values into a shell command has the potential for disaster, because they can be spoofed, so be careful with that.

Try the following:

```
// Make sure that the remote address is an IP and not something harmful, like "1.1.1.1; rm ../ -rf".
$found = preg_match('/^(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}$/', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

if($found)
{
        $command = escapeshellcmd('geoiplookup '.escapeshellarg($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
        $output = shell_exec($command);

        if(($_SESSION['check']!=1) && (strpos($output,'US')!==false || strpos($output,'AU')!==false || strpos($output,'GB')!==false || strpos($output,'CA')!==false))
        {   
                $submission = $_POST['submission_id'];
                $_SESSION['check'] = 1;
                echo 'insert pixel';
        }   
}
```

Comment: +1 for the security comments.  Running a shell command with raw user input is a crazy thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with `$output=US`
if you want to compare two operands you should use `==` operator